# Archive Manager's 'Other Options" greyed out

Tags: 18.04, encryption, archive

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I'd like to encrypt files (and the filenames as well) with Archive Manager. Unfortunately I cannot do it since the option to do so is greyed out.

[image]

Is there any solution to this?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is this file located? I'd *guess* it's a permission on the file, or file location. (Ignore that, I looked at the image again...)

What you *could* try as a workaround is `gpg` to test encrypting the file: `gpg -c purplesky2.png`

Comment: Tried that, it didn't work.

gpg -c purplesky2.png
gpg: can't open 'purplesky2.png': No such file or directory
gpg: symmetric encryption of 'purplesky2.png' failed: No such file or directory

I was hoping that I could do this via the Archive Manager, not the Terminal. Unless of course, terminal's the only way.

Comment: Terminal isn't the only way - but you'd need to `cd /home/andree/Picutres` for that command to work... :) Also (and this is only *theoretical* but I don't *know* if you can do this on `.tar.gz` - can you try another file type?)

Comment: https://postimg.cc/0Mk691BQ
https://postimg.cc/7GK56tFN

Hi, I tried the 'cd' command first and it didn't work too. I tried to match the exact filename and it didn't work either.
FYI, I don't want other types of archive because I want to use either. rar or .zip formats for this. My family mostly uses Windows and not other OS and I want them to open encrypted archives without switching OS :D

Comment: Weird - I attempted to same method as you, and using `.tar` doesn't allow me to access this information via the GUI, but other formats do. All the examples I found [pipe the tar file to gpg](https://gist.github.com/da-n/212fc19c85d81bb33272f39a5a08dedb) as opposed to the GUI method - not sure if a limitation - but [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95920/encrypt-tar-gz-file-on-create) is a good example.

Comment: "FYI, I don't want other types of archive because I want to use either. rar or .zip formats for this." - Change the format in the GUI to this then? Not `.tar.gz`? Besides, 7Zip can handle it IIRC.